# ASP.NET Core : TryValidateModel throws NullReferenceException when Controller calls another Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-validation

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC view that contains different types of entities. The view is handled by a `MainController` that calls the individual entities' controller based on a discriminator. This has been working fine until I started using custom validation attributes that require my `dbContext` to lookup data from the database.

An example of the `MainController` calling an `EntityController` looks like this. I tried both creating a new controller instance (commented out) and direct dependency injection of the controller:

```
else if (strEntityIdentifier == "VGBKKA2")
{
    // var controller = new ValveControlsController(_context);
    // var JSONresult = await controller.Put(key, values);
    // controller.Dispose();

    var JSONresult = await _valveControlsController.Put(key, values);
}
```

In the individual entities' controllers I call the model validation like this:

```
var bValidate = TryValidateModel(model);
```

This throws a `NullReferenceException` when the controller method is called by the `MainController`. However if I call the individual controller directly it works fine.

I also tried the validation via `Objectvalidation`:

```
var validationResultList = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool bValidate = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model) , validationResultList, true);
```

This doesn't throw a `NullReferenceException` but instead I cannot get my `dbContext` in the custom `ValidationAttribute` via

```
var _context = (SvrContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(SvrContext));
```

which is working fine with the `TryValidateModel` approach.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could redirect request to another controller or move logic to another component shared between the 2 controllers.

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander the redirect was the way to go. I still don't understand why the original approach didn't work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by redirecting the request via `RedirectToAction` from the `MainController` to the corresponding `EntityController`. Thanks to @Alexander for the hint!